# Convert LIVE RTMP Stream to a LIVE MP3 stream

Tags: conversion, mp3, audio-streaming

Is it possible to convert a live RTMP stream to a live MP3 stream? How much delay should be expected?

As an example, how would I convert the following stream to a MP3 stream?

rtmp://krykeypremium1.com/RadioDispatcher/151/dj1

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User! We are always glad to help, but you apparently have two Super User accounts: [this one](https://superuser.com/users/722342/dave-krykey) and [this one](https://superuser.com/users/722344/krykey). Please take the time to utilize the following Help Center tutorial and ask the Super User staff to merge your accounts: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: [how to transform live RTMP video to live mp3 Icecast stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29682170/how-to-transform-live-rtmp-video-to-live-mp3-icecast-stream)